# How To Read The JSON response coming from facebook status graph API?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, status

I am trying to receive information of any of my particular status from facebook. The id that you see in below code is one of my status (public). I am receiving all the information but unable to use it.

For example: I want to save the comments in array so that

$comment[0]="This is test comment"

$comment[1]="Terminator II" and so on

Similarly:

$name[0]= "" // name of first commentator and so on

```html
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/425484117620600'
  );
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();      
        
  var_dump($graphObject);
```

The output of my code can be found in the picture available in the following link:
http://museumerclub.com/temp/fbq.png
..I am new so I have no reoutation and so I cant upload the photo here :(..

Summary: How to save the comments in php variables after recieving it from facebook json?
Any suggestion and answer is welcomed. Thankyou. :)

Comment: have you tried to decode the json object?

Comment: You don't have json, you have an object. You need things like `$graphObject->message` to get the *status* and if you look at the source, the indenting will probably tell you how to get the rest.

Comment: @jeroen__ I have tried $graphObject->message as well as $graphObject->backingData->message and I get the following error in the log: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property Facebook\GraphObject::$backingData

Comment: If it is part of a protected property, you need to look in the package for a getter method.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a stupid question but what is this "package for a getter method" you talking about? Anyways Thank you very much for your replies.